# LiteMage Cache not working for logged in users Magento

Tags: caching, magento2, cache-control, litespeed

For my magento 2 website which uses  Litemage cache,  Once the litemage cwral is done I can see public pages are being cached. I wanted to cache private pages as well.  For private cache, Actually, I checked using multiple user accounts. When one user logs in and visits a particular page, it is cached for all the logged-in users.   Is there a way  way for the private cache to be prebuilt for logged in users?

I logged in with a different user account and checked the same page, and it is getting cached. So, it seems like we need to visit all the pages with one user account in order for the cache to work for all the logged-in users. Is that correct?

If so, could you please let me know whether there is any solution to crawl the website as a logged-in user?